# Upgrading Visual Studio 2017 to 2022, getting build errors LNK2038

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

[image]

These build errors are only happening on Release build.  Debug build is fine.  I have 2 projects.  One Solution is an .exe with some supporting .dll projects.  All of them are dependent on a project that produces a .lib

One of the projects:
[image]

The .lib project:

[image]

The other update was to the boost library.  I went from 67 to 78 . . .

[image]

It appeared that boost 78 could handle project builds from the v143 toolset.

Comment: Is this upgrade or new installation of 2022? I have 2017 and not sure what will happen if first uninstall it before installing 2022. But with upgrade will waste many GB of SSD.

Comment: New installation.  Got a new computer.  Wanted to update to all the latest software. So, installed VS 2022.  Cloned the repo.  Setup the environment.  Then was receiving those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .vcxproj and change the occurrences of v143 to be v142